# 404 page not found error even though the page exists

Tags: path-aliases, http-request, google-search-console

On my Drupal 7 website, I'm getting a 404 page not found error on the front page: http://mydomain.com even though I can view the page just fine. Google Webmaster tools wouldn't validate my site; w3 website validator stops with 404 error.

I looked at my error logs in the database, and noticed that this is coming from node/1 which doesn't exist anymore. I set my home page to a different node, node/133.

This doesn't make sense to me. Either a page exists or it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this after a lot of hair-pulling and gnashing of teeth by adding a URL alias from node/133 to node/1. Google Webtools now validates, and do does w3 link validator.

I discovered the solution by looking in the error logs:
 - admin/reports/page-not-found

I noticed that the specific page throwing the error was node/1 . Neither google Webmaster Tools, nor the validator helped as they reported only the 404 on the main domain name.